# Run SSIS 2012 Script in SQL Server 2016

Tags: ssis, etl, sql-server-2016

I've looked around and haven't found anything related to this asked as of yet.

I work on a team that needs to have our ETL run on SQL Server 2012, 2014 and 2016. This ETL only moves information around databases within the same server instance, so it won't communicate with an outside server at all. I have an old but simple script that was originally built for SSIS 2008, but was upgraded once already to SSIS 2012. When we run our configuration tool that sets up our ETL job agents, I can get that SSIS 2012 script to run successfully on SQL Server 2012, as well as on SQL Server 2014 as SQL Server auto migrates the script to 2014, however it fails to configure or run on SQL Server 2016.

What confuses me is that if I go in and do a conversion before deploying, when I actually open up the dtsx files converted for 2014 and 2016 and compare, there isn't a single difference between them, whereas comparing either to the SSIS 2012 file does show quite a few differences, but most of them are reference changes (from SSIS.Package.3 to Microsoft.Package for instance).

We'd ideally like to have only 1 source script that we deploy so we're not trying to make the same changes across multiple different solutions to support the 3 server versions. Since Microsoft made their SSDT2016 backward compatible in SSIS to SQL Server 2012, we were hoping that meant we could use the same 2012 script for all 3 as well.

Why would the script successfully migrate and run on SQL Server 2014, but not SQL Server 2016, when the 2014/2016 files are the same? Can SQL Server 2016 not convert SSIS 2012 files like SQL Server 2014 can?

Comment: Without seeing the script, it's difficult to say.

Comment: What client are you trying to run this from?  And what server is that client talking to?  I have a newer SQL server that I simply cannot use the older versions of SSIS on.  It just crashes all over the place.

Comment: @durbnpoisn The ETL script just moves information between different databases within the same server instance, so it'll never talk to an outside server instance.

Comment: Huh...  I thought you were describing trying to get the information from one server to another.  Well, it still comes back to what client you are using to execute the script.  Is it the newest version?

Comment: @Gareth Unfortunately I don't think I could post the script due to proprietary issues, but the only changes that I can see is that 2014 and 2016 add a <TargetServerVersion Type="3" Value="130" /> tag, change the package format version from 6 to 8, and then change a few references such as SSIS.Package.3 => Microsoft.Package and the component class IDs from a HEX string to Microsoft.OLEDBSource and the like.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Everything we are running would be the newest versions available as of now, so the newest version of our client, with SQL Server 2016 with the latest updates run on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that by simply adding in the TargetServerVersion tag as shown below within both DTS:ObjectData tags in the SSIS 2012 project file we were able to get the script to migrate and run in all 3 SQL Server versions:

`<DTS:ObjectData>
    <InnerObject>
        <!--Preexisting tags for other parameters-->
        <TargetServerVersion Type="3" Value="110" />
    </InnerObject>
</DTS:ObjectData>`